# Converting a string to integer in Java

Tags: java, parsing

What is the easiest way to parse a Number inside of a string in Java?
Such as: String num="123";

Comment: The Eclipse I'm familiar with is an IDE, what programming language?

Comment: Are you asking how to find the numbers in a string like `14 / 2 + 5`?

Comment: no but if you can tell me that that would be appercaited its not part of my question though

Comment: This question was already answered but reformatted for others to understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int n = Integer.parseInt(s)` in Java.